# Is it possible to disable IndexedDB in angular?

Tags: angular, iframe, angular5, indexeddb

IndexedDB is restricted in cross-origin iframes in Safari and new versions of Chromium, which makes our embedded angular5 app unusable for those cases. Is it possible to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB can't be disabled as it's API comes from the browser.

IndexedDB by default is limited to the [Same-Origin Policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), and since your usecase is to pass data between iframes, you can do it via the window.message function which is not limited cross domain.

I found a [sample code](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384) which uses `localstorage` and `window.message` to pass data between `iframes` on different domain, I think it might work for your case as well.

Comment: I'm not asking how to pass data between iframes, my question is how to disable IndexedDB in angular.

Comment: Hey vovafeldman, since the default browser behaviour is to prevent data be shared with indexeddb across domains, I would suggest to deprecate this function (storing data in indexeddb) completely.